# Jquery for customized right click, in my application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

In my application I need to disable the `RIGHT click` and I did this.

But now I need to do the customized `RIGHT click` menu which contains only `COPY` and `PASTE` options.

Is there any `way` or any `plugin` to do this for only `COPY` and `PASTE` options.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Why oh why would you want to do this? The right click menu _already has_ the copy and paste options. Disabling browser functionality for users is an awful, awful practice.

Comment: You won't be able to modify the browser's context menu, however you can make your own using HTML/CSS with jQuery. Check out some good examples here: http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/right-click-context-menu-plugins/

Comment: why a negative vote ?

Comment: While I don't really agree with the purpose of the question, this is the way to answer it. +1

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Because my application doesn't need the other functions for some privacy.My BOSS asked me to do this .

Comment: This is not the way to answer the question, it just links to another site that already has warning comments from users there about the content of the list. The proper way to answer a question on SO is to provide a code example and possibly a live example, not just link off to some other place that could one day vanish.

Comment: @KitePlayer I can understand your question,@leonard already answered the possible answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I cant find a source code there. I already seen this site and it doesn't helped me.

Comment: @Red But I cant find a source code there. I already seen this site and it doesn't helped me.Any more suggestions by you ?

Comment: I agree Kyle to a certain extent - to be fair it would be more helpful to post an example, but at the same time when all it takes is a simple Google search I was reluctant to go ahead and write/copy a chunk of code and await further "but this needs changing, this doesn't work" type comments. But I take that on board - thanks

@KitePlayer The demos are there, you just need to view the source of those demos to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks and ok .. I will do it now and let you know if I have any doubts.